# Firebase Signin doesn't work after signout

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

On my Unity Project, I have this piece of code for signing in using Google Authenticatoin.

```
public void GoogleSignInClick()
    {
        configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration { WebClientId = GoogleWebAPI, RequestIdToken = true };

        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;  //line2
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;
        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthenticatedFinished);
    }
```

I also have a code

```
 public void SignOut()
    {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;          
        auth.SignOut();     
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("signingoogle");
    }
```

The problem is that signin function works fine when I load the app. But it doesn't work after I signout. The issue is at line2 in the signin function.

Since I'm building this on a mobile, I'm unable to see exact error. But what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
if (GoogleSignIn.Configuration == null)
{
  GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
  GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
}
```